# navigation.setOptions not change

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i'm creating screens with react-navigator but i can not change the options of the Header Bar when screen opened

My code (App.js):

```
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} />,
        headerRight: props => <HeaderRight {...props} />,
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#F46A0D'
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
      }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My SearchScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper'

const SearchScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    navigation.setOptions = {
        headerTitle: props => <TextInput {...props} placeholder="Search" placeholderTextColor="#FFFF" style={{
            fontSize: 24
        }}></TextInput>,
        headerRight: props => <FontAwesome5 {...props} name={'search'} size={22} color="white" style={{ marginRight: 15 }}></FontAwesome5>
    }
    return (
        <View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default SearchScreen;
```

in the navigation.setOptions line nothing happens and the default screenOptions Stack.Navigator continues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this

```js
navigation.setOptions = {
  headerTitle: props => <TextInput {...props} placeholder="Search" placeholderTextColor="#FFFF" style={{
    fontSize: 24
  }}></TextInput>,
  headerRight: props => <FontAwesome5 {...props} name={'search'} size={22} color="white" style={{ marginRight: 15 }}></FontAwesome5>
}
```

to this:

```js
navigation.setOptions({
  headerTitle: props => <TextInput {...props} placeholder="Search" placeholderTextColor="#FFFF" style={{
    fontSize: 24
  }} />,
  headerRight: props => <FontAwesome5 {...props} name={'search'} size={22} color="white" style={{ marginRight: 15 }}></FontAwesome5>
})
```

Comment: what is a technical difference between these two? Both look same for me. Thanks

Comment: in this case "navigation.setOptions = {" you just destroy the setOptions function by replacing it with data. which is not the correct usecase :)

Answer (score 7):

on route file

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="FuncName"
    component={FuncName}
    options={{
    headerTitle:''
}}/>
```

on Press go to FuncName screen

```
onPress={()=>{
    props.navigation.navigate("FuncName",{title:"title"})
  }}
```

then change header by props title

```
const FuncName = (props) => {
useEffect(()=>{
      props.navigation.setOptions({ headerTitle: props.route.params.title  })
  },[])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was able to make it possible to update "gestureEnabled" option in runtime using React lifecycle.

Each of my navigators was created as function that subscribes to UiContext value via hook.

In case of navigators re-rendering on dependency change, I was able to disable "swipe back" functionality on specific nested screen easily.